# The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.3.0) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.3.0) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.2.2

I am trying to open my team mate project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

change the version to 7.2.2 in gradle file as shown in the image

Answer (score 0):

you need to com.android.application version to 7.2.2 in project level build.gradle
For detail information
please Refer this link
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility

Comment: The phrasing "you need to com.android.application version to 7.2.2 in project level build.gradle" is too unclear to serve as the required summary of how the solution can be applied. And without such an understandable summary, your post risks being considere a link-only answer, which usually gets flagged and deleted as not providing a solution directly here. You might rephrase by adding a verb and other details. Maybe something like "You need to set the version of your com.android.application to 7.2.2 in the project level configuration paragraph 'build.gradle'."

Answer (score -1):

Update your Android Studio to Dolphin version.
[image: AGP Version x Android Studio]

For more, see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility) link.